# $\bigl(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x_j+y_j|^p\bigr)^{1/p}\leq \bigl(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x_j|^p\bigr)^{1/p}+\bigl(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|y_j|^p\bigr)^{1/p}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have two lemmas and I don't quite understand how the second one is really proved.

Here's the first lemma:

Lemma 1: (Minkowski's inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$). For all $1\leq p \leq \infty$ if $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then (1) $$\|x+y\|_{l^p}\leq \|x\|_{l^p}+\|y\|_{l^p}$$

Lemma 2: (Minkowski's inequality in the sequence space $l^p$). For all $1\leq p\leq \infty$ if $x,y\in l^p$ then $$\|x+y\|_{l^p}\leq \|x\|_{l^p}+\|y\|_{l^p}$$

Proof: The case $p=\infty$ is straightforward. For $p\in[1,\infty)$, given $x,y\in l^p$, we can use (1) to guarantee that $$\biggl(\sum^n_{j=1}|x_j+y_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}\leq \biggl(\sum^n_{j=1}|x_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}+\biggl(\sum^n_{j=1}|y_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}\leq \|x\|_{l^p}+\|y\|_{l^p}$$

Now, I don't understand how this proves the fact that $$\biggl(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x_j+y_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}\leq \biggl(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}+\biggl(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|y_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}$$

Can someone explain what is the logic behind their proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first double inequality gives that for all $n$,
$$\biggl(\sum^n_{j=1}|x_j+y_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}\leq \|x\|_{l^p}+\|y\|_{l^p} = \biggl(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|x_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}+\biggl(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|y_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}$$.

Now $\biggl(\sum^n_{j=1}|x_j+y_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}$ is increasing w.r.t. $n$ and thus the limit exist and it is less or equal to $\|x\|_{l^p}+\|y\|_{l^p}$. Also the limit is equal to $\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j+y_j|^p\biggr)^{1/p}$. That you can see since the function $x \mapsto x^{1/p}$ is continuous.